# Firefox keeps crashing

Tags: firefox

When I open FireFox it crashes about 5 seconds later, and this is the error:

```
Add-ons: globalmenu%40ubuntu.com:3.6.4,langpack-en-GB%40firefox.mozilla.org:17.0.1,langpack-en-ZA%40firefox.mozilla.org:17.0.1,langpack-zh-CN%40firefox.mozilla.org:17.0.1,ubufox%40ubuntu.com:2.6,%7B972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd%7D:17.0.1
BuildID: 20121129151842
CrashTime: 1355583809
EMCheckCompatibility: true
FramePoisonBase: 7ffffffff0dea000
FramePoisonSize: 4096
InstallTime: 1355581168
Notes: OpenGL: X.Org -- Gallium 0.4 on AMD RS780 -- 2.1 Mesa 9.0 -- texture_from_pixmap

ProductID: {ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}
ProductName: Firefox
ReleaseChannel: release
SecondsSinceLastCrash: 598
StartupTime: 1355583804
Theme: classic/1.0
Throttleable: 1
URL: http://shop.ubuntu.com/
Vendor: Mozilla
Version: 17.0.1

This report also contains technical information about the state of the application when it crashed.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try opening Firefox in safe mode. This will disable the addons, so you'll be able to see whether the bug is in Firefox, or an add-on.

If it does not crash, try enabling your add-ons one by one, to find the one which is crashing Firefox.